# Symfony2 how to validate unique email using validator component

Tags: php, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.8

Im creating an application that creates users from a CSV file, so there is no Forms. **i'm using the symfony validator component to validate the data inside the controller**. so far ive created a helper function that takes in the data and the constraints and returns out the error if any. here is what i mean.

The helper function

```
public function csverror($value, $constraint, $rowcount, $columnname){
    $error = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($value, $constraint);
    if(count($error) !== 0){
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('csverror', "error on line: $rowcount column: $columnname ". $error[0]->getMessage());
    }
}
```

and calling it inside the controller action

```
$this->csverror($associativerow['email'],  array(new NotBlank(), new Length(['max' => 100]), new Email()), $rowcount, "email");
```

Here i need to check if the email specified in the CSV already exists in the database, for this im assuming that [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) has to be used. It has an associated class called [UniqueEntityValidator](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Validator/Constraints/UniqueEntityValidator.html). The amazing thing is that the Validator Component has a feature that **automatically** checks the locale and displays the error messages in that language!! (*i'm guessing its through the [ConstraintViolation](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolation.html) object*). I would like to utilize this feature instead of the bland `findOneBy()` to query the database and check if the email already exists and returning with an error message using (comparatively) messy xliff files.

so! the question is how to validate for unique email in the database using the validator component's [validator service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#using-the-validator-service)

edit: in the above code `$associativerow['email']` is a string, but in practice i can have it as a `User` object if necessary, you can have the liberty to assume its an entity object if needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid this is not possible using `UniqueEntity` and its `UniqueEntityValidator`, because this last require an entity object as value to validate. Otherwise, will throw an exception:

> "get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given"

You would be forced to find the entity instance for this email before and then pass this to `$this->csverror(...)` method:

```
$object = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(['email' => $associativerow['email']]);
$this->csverror($object, new UniqueEntity(...));
```

#### EDIT:

If you have the user instance then don't you need settings the constraints to validate it in you `csverror` function. Configure the assert constraints inside you entity User class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * ...
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}
 */
class User 
{
    //...

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max="100")
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $email;

    //...
}
```

later,

```
public function csverror($object, $rowcount){
    $error = $this->container->get('validator')->validate($object);
    // ...
}
```

and,

```
$user = new User();
$user->setEmail($associativerow['email']);
// ...

$this->csverror($user, $rowcount);
```

Now, the `UniqueEntity` constraint validate unique user by email field.

Comment: Updated answer using constraint into model class.